# (VBA) Unable to .Find when using .Cells within .Range

Tags: excel, vba, variables, find, range

I am trying to write a basic function that will search for text within a header row, the start point will always be A1 but the end point will be variable.

I can get the function to work if I hard code the Range, but am experiencing issues when converting it to a variable.

```
    'sample of working code:
     
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:I1").Find(Text).Column

    function = rng
```

Issues begin when I try to make ("A1"I1") more dynamic...

```
    '1st example 

    'Obtain the variable right hand side for the range                    (works fine)
        Dim lCol As Long
        lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   

    'Use the variable in the Range                                     (Does not work)
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng= ActiveSheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol)).Find("text").Column

    '(For display only this limits the .Find parameters to WHAT)
```

Using the .Cells property within the Range gave a compile error: "Invalid or unqualified reference" so I tried moving the search range into a variable and using that in the .Find...

```
    '2nd example

    'Obtain the variable right hand side for the range                   (works fine)
        Dim lCol As Long
        lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  
  
    'Create a variable to feed into the Range.Find                       (works fine)
       Dim cellRange As Range
       Set cellRange = ActiveSheet.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol))

    'Use the new variable in the Range                                (Does not work)
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng= ActiveSheet.Range(cellRange).Find("text").Column
```

...This gave the same error

I have successfully expressed Range using .Cells when changing Font for example, and am confident the below is "good" code... I just cannot workout why I cannot use it combined with .Find

```
 .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(1, lCol))
```

Please could somebody in the community help me, ideally I'd like to achieve two things:

1. Getting this code to work
2. To understand why I can express Range using cells when I change cell attributes like font but not in Find - it seems contradictory to me so must be missing key information

Thank you in advance

Marc

Comment: You're missing the `With ActiveSheet` that the `.Cells` should be referring to.

Comment: Why not just use the entire row though? It doesn't make much sense to limit the range to just up to the last column. `Application.Match` might be even better here.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I was limiting to the populated cells out of habit but searching the entire row won't significantly slow things down so have gone with that.